# Proving that S+T could be an epimorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $S, T$: $U \rightarrow V$ are both epimorphisms. Is it necessary that S + T is an epimorphism?

So I know that what I need to prove is that $I(S+T) = V$ is or isn't necessary... But I'm kinda confused on how can I approach the problem... Can someone give an hint?

Comment: No; Think of T=-S.

Answer (score 0):

In general this is bot true, as cjackal said above $S=-T$ gives a counterexample. Less trivial counterexample is:

$S,T:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ are isomorphism such that:

$S(1,0)=-2T(1,0)$ and $S(0,1)=-T(0,1)$ then $(S+T)(1,0)=-T(1,0)$ which is different to zero vector since $S,T$ are isomorphism, but $(S+T)(0,1)=(0,0)$. So there exists two isomorphism (in particular epimorphism) such that the sum is not injective, since the dimensions of the source and the target are the the same, the sum is not an epimorphism.